# How to get a character line from a website with Javascript

Tags: javascript

What i want to do is to get a line of character from a website which has a token generator that generates every time it opens a new code and then put into my link.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here... Could you try to explain better? Maybe provide a better example?

Comment: Okay sorry for that, all im trying to do is to get a string from a website .aspx which has a token generator and then add into my link like this : mylink.com + the token i got from the website

Comment: The JS code will need to make an HTTP request and then process the result. Without some information on the target page one cannot help with the nature of that parsing.

Comment: Why is this question tagger `java`? (Java and JavaScript are almost completely different languages.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you want :

```
    var link = "mylink.com/"+result ;
```

Comment: kinda of it but i want that the result to be a variable which gets the string from a website with a token